# How does one get the value of a button click in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

I am trying to understand how the connection between a controller and a view works. I have set up four buttons with the tag `asp-action` expecting it to allow me to implement a method with the name `check`

```
<table style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 25px">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button name="button" style="background-color: transparent; color: yellow" 
                    type="button" value="cph" asp-action="check">København</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button style="background-color: transparent; color: yellow" type="button" value="odense" asp-action="check">Odense</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button style="background-color: transparent; color: yellow" type="button" value="aarhus" asp-action="check">Århus</button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button style="background-color: transparent; color: yellow" type="button" value="aalborg" asp-action="check">Aalborg</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I tried to print the value of the button

```
public IActionResult check(string button)
{
    Console.WriteLine(button);
    return View();
}
```

However, it does never print anything, nor does it break on the method. What I would like to achieve is just the value. I would prefer just passing the value and do nothing e.g.

```
public striing check(string button)
{
    return button;
}
```

EDIT:
I tried following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2nOieuwix2A)

Comment: Buttons don't really work this way in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: I don't think `asp-controller` and `asp-action` Form Tag Helpers work on HTML `button`. All examples are either on links or forms. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-3.1#asp-action

Comment: you need to set `name` attribute of an input/button element to send its data with the request, otherwise browser just omits it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When we access data from a view to the controller's action method, we could use the Parameter method to get the form value, by using this method the input field **Name** and parameter **Name** should be the same. So, if you want to get button value, it should have the same Name value (but in your sample code, only the first button has a name attribute).

Second, when we using the `<button>` tag, it will implicitly submit the form, but if we add "type='button'" for the `<button>` tag, the button will not submit the form, so the action method not executed. To solve this issue, you could remove the `type="button"` or change it to `type="submit"`.

So, you could modify your code as below (use the same name value and remove the `type="button"`):

```
<form>    
    <table style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 25px">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button name="button" style="background-color: transparent; color: yellow"
                         value="cph" asp-action="check">
                    København
                </button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button name="button" style="background-color: transparent; color: yellow"  value="odense" asp-action="check">Odense</button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button name="button" style="background-color: transparent; color: yellow" value="aarhus" asp-action="check">Århus</button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button name="button" style="background-color: transparent; color: yellow" value="aalborg" asp-action="check">Aalborg</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</form>
<div>
    @TempData["ButtonValue"]
</div>
```

Code in the controller:

```
    public IActionResult ButtonClick()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public IActionResult check(string button)
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(button))
        { 
            TempData["ButtonValue"] = string.Format("{0} button clicked.", button);
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["ButtonValue"] = "No button click!";
        }
        return RedirectToAction("ButtonClick");
    }
```

Then, the result like this:

[image]

Comment: We click a button on a web page to do some specific action like: POST data to new page or use AJAX. And ASP.NET does not do it. Javascript does.